# String parameters

Tags: c++, go, swig

I'm trying to use swig to interface with c++, and I'm having problems using a `std::string&` parameter.  This is on Fedora 19 with golang 1.1-2, swig 2.0.10-1, and gcc 4.8.1-1.

I don't know C++. I do know C, and had hoped to wing it. At any rate, `_swig_wrap_pinput` ends up with a null pointer.

What am I overlooking?

Here's my test case:

**st.i**

```
%module st
%{
#include <string>
extern void pinput(std::string& pstring);
%}
%include <std_string.i>
#include <string>
void pinput(std::string& pstring);
```

**st.cxx**

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void pinput(std::string& pstring) {
  std::cout<<pstring;
}
```

**stmain.go**

```
package main
import (
       "st"
)

func main() {
     myLit:="This is a test."
     st.Pinput(&myLit)
}
```

**Makefile**

```
SWIGOBJS = st_gc.c st_wrap.cxx st.go

all: st.so st.a

$(SWIGOBJS):    st.i
    swig -go -c++ -intgosize 64 st.i

st.o:   st.cxx
    g++ -c -fpic -g -o st.o st.cxx

st_wrap.o:  st_wrap.cxx
    g++ -c -fpic -g -o st_wrap.o st_wrap.cxx

st.so:  st_wrap.o st.o
    g++ -shared st_wrap.o st.o -o st.so

st_gc.6:    st_gc.c
    /usr/lib64/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6c -I /usr/lib64/golang/pkg/linux_amd64 st_gc.c

st.6:   st.go
    /usr/lib64/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6g st.go
st.a:   st.6 st_gc.6
    go tool pack grc st.a st.6 st_gc.6

test: stmain

stmain: stmain.6
    /usr/lib64/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6l stmain.6

stmain.6: stmain.go
    /usr/lib64/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6g stmain.go
```

Comment: Your `pinput` function takes it as a reference, not a const reference. If you don't modify the string, pass by const reference and then the interface gets a whole lot simpler.

Comment: I made that change, but it didn't materially change the generated interface code, or the performance.

Comment: I don't know Go, however based on my experience with SWIG for Lua, Python, C# and Java, I find strange that your Go code calls Pinput whereas your sWIG export exposes pinput without any rename for uppercase. Is Go not case-sensitive? If it is, somehow  _swig_wrap_pinput is still being called, so SWIG knows that st.Pinput maps to C++ pinput... odd. I'm also surprised that you give Pinput the address of myLit (presumably, a Go pointer), whereas the C++ side expects a reference to a string. I would look into those two aspects further.

Comment: @Schollii Yes go is case sensitive. 

Also Go strings and std::String are different. Go strings are essentially stored like so:

struct {
   unsigned int len, cap;
   char *str;
}

When you pass a string in go, it passes that struct, not a pointer to it.

Comment: Keep in mind you don't need to use SWIG. You can create a C wrapper that Go calls, that is declared "extern C" and have those function talk C++ as needed. Example: https://github.com/burke/howto-go-with-cpp

Comment: I think I recall reading that Go &pointers != C &pointers.  You have to do as voidlogic said and extern C the functions for Go to call.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question was originally asked both Go and SWIG have updated. I will post a solution that worked for me (Go 1.3.3, SWIG 3.0.2). As you can see, the difference to the original post is minimal.

The most recommended approach is to use *go build*. It knows nowadays to look for *.swig and *.swigcxx files, and runs both SWIG and GCC/G++ automatically based on the information found in the swig interface file.

**stmain.go**

```
package main
import (
       "st" // This will be created by SWIG
)

func main() {
     myLit:="This is a test."
     st.Pinput(myLit)
}
```

**st/st.h**

```
ifndef ST_H
#define ST_H

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void pinput(const std::string& pstring);

#endif
```

**st/st.cpp**

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void pinput(const std::string& pstring) {
  std::cout << pstring;
  std::cout << std::endl; // Without endl the stdout doesn't get flushed for me -> no output
}
```

**st/st.go**

```
package st
// Without any Go file in the directory the go build will fail
```

**st/st.swigcxx**

```
%module st
%include "std_string.i"
%include "st.h"
%{
extern void pinput(const std::string& pstring);
%}

void pinput(const std::string& pstring);
```

**To build & run**

```
// Quick'n'dirty version
# go build stmain.go
# ./stmain
This is a test.
#
```

Alternatively you can build the same sources manually with 6g/c/l/swig/gotool, for example my simplified version:

**Makefile:**

```
all:
    make -C st
    /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6g -I st stmain.go
    /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6l -o stmain -extldflags -lstdc++ -L st stmain.6
clean:
    rm -f *.6 6.out
    make clean -C st

test: stmain
```

**st/Makefile:**

```
all: clean
        swig -go -intgosize 64 -c++ -soname st.so st.swigcxx
        g++ -c st.cpp -o st.o
        g++ -c st_wrap.cxx -o st_wrap.o
        /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6c -I /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/ -D _64BIT st_gc.c
        /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6g st.go 
        go tool pack grc st.a st.6 st_gc.6 st.o st_wrap.o

clean:
        rm -f *.6
        rm -f *.a
        rm -f *.so
        rm -f *.cxx
        rm -f *.c
        rm -f *.o
```