# Golang: How to link C objects using CGO_OFILES?

Tags: go, makefile

I'm pulling my hair out because of this.

All I want to do is link a .o (C object file) with a Go package so the Go package can call the C functions.

There does not appear to be any documentation on `CGO_OFILES` parameter of cgo, which appears to be what I need after much Internet searching.

I've tried putting this at the top of the Go file:

```
/*
#cgo CGO_OFILES: doc-capi-tesseract.o
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "doc-capi-tesseract.h"
*/
import "C"
```

But that gives me the error `invalid #cgo verb: #cgo CGO_OFILES: doc-capi-tesseract.o`. Then I read somewhere that a makefile can be used, so I made this probably incorrect makefile:

```
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.inc
TARG=tesseract
CGOFILES=tesseract.go
CGO_OFILES=doc-capi-tesseract.o
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.pkg

%.o: %.cpp
    $(HOST_CC) $(CGO_CFLAGS_$(GOARCH)) -g -O2 -fPIC -o $@ -c $^
```

But I have no idea then what to do with that file. Nothing happens if I run `make` or `make myfile` or `go build makefile`. No idea how to use it.

Could someone please explain to me how to link a Go file to a C object file?

Comment: What leads you to beliueve that there is a `CGO_OFILES` variable?

Comment: It's mentioned in a few different places. If you search for it you'll see. It's not documented though.

Comment: I guess it's gone away. Grepping through the source of cgo, I couln't find any reference to that.

Comment: You mean to say it used to exist but does not exist in the current version? If so it surely must have been replaced with something else?

Comment: I don't know. Is the object file you want to link generate from C source code in your case or do you want to ship literally an object file?

Comment: I've managed to link to a `.a` don't know if that helps you? (https://github.com/d2g/gomq)

Comment: I think the point is that you are not supposed to place binaries or object files inside go gettable repositories.

Comment: I'm not creating a Go Gettable repository, just an executable for my own internal use.

Answer (score 4):

1. You could use [SWIG](http://swig.org/Doc3.0/Go.html) because it gives you more versatility. I just learnt myself to use it with C++ ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753105/string-parameters/27259193#27259193)) but the process is 99% similar with C. You can choose between static and dynamic linking, both approaches will work.
2. You can force CGO to link statically ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747021/how-do-you-statically-link-a-c-library-in-go-using-cgo), see especially the mentioned github repo!) by defining correct flags.

Example to #2:

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -Isrc/include  
// Where doc-capi-tesseract.h is!
// #cgo LDFLAGS: doc-capi-tesseract.a
// #include "doc-capi-tesseract.h"

import "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **.syso** istead of **.o** extension.

**go build** now automatically links every .syso files found in derectory into your binary.