# Can swig + golang handle a std::string out param?

Tags: c++, go, swig

I'm trying to connect a go project to a C++ lib using SWIG.  I've got most things working, but there's one function that takes a C++ std::string as a param and assigns a value to it, and I haven't been able to get that working.

The closest thing I've found online is this question: [String parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753105/string-parameters)

It's not the same since it takes a `const std::string &`, and SWIG translates that to a go string.

My function looks something like:

`bool foo(std::string &result);`

SWIG converts this to `func Foo(result *string) boolean`

This compiles and builds, but if I pass in a pointer to a go string, it panics.

```
var result string
Foo(&result)
```

I have been able to make foo() return a std::string, which SWIG seems to make work with a go string just fine.  However, I lose the return value in this case.

I'm using golang 1.7, swig 3.0.10

Comment: can you put your failing example up somewhere?

Comment: I don't remember exactly how I got around this, but I think I used a wrapper that converted the string to a `char *`.

Comment: The code generated by swig 3.0.12 casts the Go String reference to a `void*` that is finally casted into a `std::string*`. So it crashes. 
@dragonx What do you mean by _I lose the return value in this case_ ?

Comment: @david It's been a while since I've looked at this.  My solution was to convert the std::string& to a char*, and pass a char* instead.  The early solution I had was to have Foo() return a std::string, which worked, but that also mean that Foo() could no longer return a meaningful error code.